# wskdeploy not recognized error on Windows 10 CLI

Tags: openwhisk

I have just gone through the OpenWhisk-wskdeploy [set up page](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-wskdeploy#running-wskdeploy).

After building the tool (`godep go build -o wskdeploy`) I got the wskdeploy file available in the working dir (`src/github.com/apache/openwhisk-wskdeploy/`).

When I try to test the build though I got the following:

```
C:\Users\decaro\go\src\github.com\apache\openwhisk-wskdeploy>.\wskdeploy --help
'.\wskdeploy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: This tool is also bundled with the `wsk` cli and released as a convenience for windows here https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-cli/releases/tag/latest